# How does Application Server remove invalid or inactive sessions from storage?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee

As far as I know, Application Server such as WebSphere or WebLogic can store users' sessions (I mean `httpSession`) in memory or in different persistent storages. So the question is, what mechanisms does App Server use to remove old or invalid sessions from its storage?

Comment: A bit too vague - the app servers just delete the session from the corresponding datastore depending on storage type (e.g. database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most helpful thing that I have found is [WebSphere Session Management](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4580.pdf) guide. Although it contains rather general information it contains some kind of answer for this question. And also it seems to be quite up-to-date (2009).

And in general, the answer is, that there is a kind of scheduled worker / thread managed by AppServer which checks out all of stored sessions every N seconds and removes expired ones.

Answer (score 1):

For closed-source servers you named, it's difficult to say without asking Oracle or IBM. My guess would be they use an embedded DB or a distributed cache that must be able to replicate itself across nodes in a cluster of servers, and they periodically check for outdated sessions and then delete them.

Don't know how helpful it is?

Comment: The most interesting thing for me is how do they "check for outdated sessions and then delete them".